# How to make an AJAX request and respond with laravel?

Tags: ajax, laravel

My method returns nothing when I do a `vardump`.
I need to get the resource and show a modal one but I don't get a response from the AJAXhave no method return
AJAX

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/modalAjax",
    data: "id=" + obj.id,  
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function() {
        $('#modalEdit').modal('show');
    },
    error: function() {

    }
});
```

CONTROLLER

```
public function modalAjax(Request $request) {        
    var_dump($request); 
    die();
    return Response::json($request);        
}
```

Comment: try `dd($request->all);` instead of `var_dump`

Comment: Welcome to SO. I've reworded the question title and description a bit. FYI, you are making the request with JavaScript, which reaches the server, and then you're using Laravel to process and respond to that request (an AJAX request).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a view setup like this

```html
{{-- Add a CSRF token --}}
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
{{-- Just to avoid Vue console warning --}}
<div id="app"></div>
{{-- Include the JQuery library --}}
<script src="/js/app.js"></script>
<script>
    // add csrf header to all Ajax requests
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
    var obj = {id: 1}; // Just an example when reproducing
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/modalAjax",
        data: "id=" + obj.id,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data); // Do anything with the data here
            $('#modalEdit').modal('show');
        },
        error: function() {
        }
    });
</script>
```

And a route like so

```php
// HomeController is just an example, link to your own
Route::post('/modalAjax', 'HomeController@modalAjax');
```

You can access the request data in your controller like so

```php
public function modalAjax(Request $request)
{
    // Do something with $request->id
    return response()->json([
        'id' => $request->id
    ]);
}
```

Now this will return the received ID as it is, don't know what you want to do with it there ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Now you'd get this in the console and the bootstrap modal should show

```
{"id":"1"}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks man, that worked. But in view I don't get obj, but in console.log yes

Comment: How to return a variable with obj to view?

Comment: I don't know what "variable with obj" you're trying to return to the view from the controller, your controller code in the question doesn't do anything, please edit the question and add the variable so I can update the answer properly

Answer (score 0):

i think you should put a function(data) inside the ajax call to retrieve data like

```
  $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/modalAjax",
            data: "id=" + obj.id,  
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
 // data is your response
                $('#modalEdit').modal('show');

            },
            error: function() {

            }
        });
```